# Why does decodeURI decode more characters than it should?

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I was just reading about `decodeURI` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI), [ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-encodeuri-uri)) and something caught my eye:

> Escape sequences that could not have been introduced by encodeURI are not replaced.

So, it should only decode characters that `encodeURI` encodes.

```js
// None of these should be escaped by `encodeURI`.
const unescaped = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.!~*'();/?:@&=+$,#";

const data = [...unescaped].map(char => ({
  "char": char,
  "encodeURI(char)": encodeURI(char),
  "encodePercent(char)": encodePercent(char),
  "decodeURI(encodePercent(char))": decodeURI(encodePercent(char))
}));

console.table( data );
console.log( "Check the browser's console." );

function encodePercent(string) {
  return string.replace(/./g, char => "%" + char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
}
```

Why is this only true for `; / ? : @ & = + $ , #`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification states the following step:

> 3. Let *unescapedURISet* be a String containing one instance of each code unit valid in *uriReserved* and *uriUnescaped* plus "#"

Let’s take a look at [*uriReserved*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-uri-syntax-and-semantics), and voilà:

> uriReserved ::: one of
>
> ```
> ; / ? : @ & = + $ ,
> ```

The following step is then:

> 4. Return Encode(uriString, unescapedURISet).

[Encode](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-encode) everything in encodes the string except for the characters in *unescapedURISet*, which include `; / ? : @ & = + $ ,`.

This means that `encodeURI` can never introduce escape sequences for anything in *uriReserved* and *uriUnescaped*.

Interestingly enough, `decodeURI` is defined like this:

> 3. Let reservedURISet be a String containing one instance of each code unit valid in *uriReserved* plus "#".
> 4. Return Decode(uriString, reservedURISet).

[Decode](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-decode) works similarly to Encode and decodes everything except for the characters in *reservedURISet*. Obviously, only the characters of *uriReserved* are excluded from being decoded. And those happen to be `; / ? : @ & = + $ ,`!

The questions remains why the standard specifies this. If they had included *uriUnescaped* in *reservedURISet* the behaviour would be exactly what the introduction states. Probably a mistake?

Comment: But how can it introduce the rest of the characters? For example `A`?

Comment: @changed I updated my answer. Technically it should answer your question now, but I’ve no idea why they defined it that way.

Comment: I will accept your answer if no one can explain why that is.